# MySQL query to get most recent entry for all users

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the most recent values for all individual users. I have a table that looks like below:

```
| id | userId | value | createdAt
1      20        1        2014-01-01
2      21        2        2014-01-05
3      20        1.5      2014-01-06
4      21        1.1      2014-01-08
```

And my desired output would be:

```
| id | userId | value | createdAt
3      20        1.5      2014-01-06
4      21        1.1      2014-01-08
```

My current Mysql query looks like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  userTable
GROUP BY userId
ORDER BY createdAt DESC
```

But this query is not solving the problem because it seems like Group By is grouping the 1st entry of user with all of its subsequent user IDs.

And then I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM userTable ORDER BY createdAt DESC) t 
GROUP BY userId
```

This returned the results I anticipated, but it seems to be a very sub-optimal solution. I anticipate the table to grow substantially, so is there a better query? "Better" as in faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Luckily, this is the most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag. It's correctly answered quite often too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
select id, userid, value, createdat
  from usertable x
 where createdat =
       (select max(y.createdat) from usertable y where y.userid = x.userid)
```

Or join into an inline view:

```
select x.*
  from usertable x
  join (select userid, max(createdat) as lastcreatedat
          from usertable
         group by userid) y
    on x.userid = y.userid
   and x.createdat = y.lastcreatedat
```

Comment: With option 2 available, why would you ever go with option 1 !?!?

Comment: although it would maybe make a small difference in mysql i imagine it would get processed identically in oracle or other databases

Comment: I can't speak for other RDBMSs but, in MySQL, option 2 will be orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a sub-query to get the max createdAt value grouped with the UserID, then create a INNER JOIN using the sub-query as the second table.

```
SELECT a.id, a.suerId, a.[value], a.createdAt
FROM userTable a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT UserID, MAX(createdAt) AS MaxCreatedAt FROM userTable b GROUPBY UserID) b
ON b.MaxCreatedAt = a.createdAt AND b.UserID = a.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2
ON t2.userID = t1.userID
AND t2.createdAt > t1.createdAt
WHERE t2.id is null
```